# get_posts works but new wp_query doesn't

Tags: wp-query, get-posts

I was told that `get_posts` is a very bad function to use that that making a `new WP_query` is absolutely better.

My problem is that my `get_posts` code works but when I tried turning it into a `WP_query`, it returns blank results. Assistance please? :( I'd really love to get this to work because  I suspect that the get_posts that I have on index.php / category-9.php are interfering with the normal loop on category.php

Get_posts version:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( (have_posts() ) ) : the_post(); ?>
  <div class="postcontainer">
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title(''); ?></a></h2>

    <?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'post_mime_type' => 'image',
        'numberposts' => 4,
        'post_status' => null,
        'post_parent' => $post->ID,
        'orderby' => name,
        'order' => ASC
    );
    $attachments = get_posts($args);
    if ($attachments) {
      foreach ($attachments as $post) {
        setup_postdata($post); ?>
          <a class="postpreview" href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->post_parent) ?>"><?php echo wp_get_attachment_image($post->ID, thumbnail) ?></a>
      <?php }; 
    }; ?>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
<?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

WP_query version:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( (have_posts() ) ) : the_post(); ?>
  <div class="postcontainer">
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title(''); ?></a></h2>

    <?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'post_mime_type' => 'image',
        'numberposts' => 4,
        'post_status' => null,
        'post_parent' => $post->ID,
        'orderby' => name,
        'order' => ASC
    );
    $attachments = new WP_Query($args);
      while ($attachments->have_posts()) : ?>
          <a class="postpreview" href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->post_parent) ?>"><?php echo wp_get_attachment_image($post->ID, thumbnail) ?></a>
      <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Comment: Why is `get_posts()` a bad function? It's just a simple wrapper for `WP_Query`. You probably meant `query_posts()`?

Comment: @birgire I actually wouldn't really know :/ It was an admonishment from someone in #wordpress@freenode and I wasn't able to ask why. I'm actually just trying it because I feel that it's the reason why my normal loop on another template file isn't working properly.

Comment: It must have been some misunderstanding ;-) Always test your code with `WP_DEBUG` activated on your test site, to see if you got any errors.

Comment: I don't know D: They very clearly said "YOU'RE USING GET POSTS. BAD." Thanks for `WP_DEBUG`! Completely forgot that I disabled that ages ago.

Comment: `'numberposts' => 4,` is deprecated, use `posts_per_page` instead.

Comment: @MayeenulIslam Thanks :) Will be updating that bit.

Comment: `get_posts()` is not a "bad" function, though it strikes me a bit unnecessary as `WP_Query` serves perfectly well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forget `$query->the_post()`, which makes the same as `setup_postdata()`. Also you are using `$post->ID` inside the loop but `$post` is not current post object in the loop. You have also syntax errors; for example you pass `thumnail` to `wp_get_attachment_image()` instead of a string `"thumbnail"`, and pass `name` as `orderby` argument instead of the string `"name"`, or `ASC` instead of `"ASC"`:

```
 <?php
 //as you are inside a loop but I don't see $post variable in your code,
 //I assume you want the current post in the loop as parent
 $parent_id = get_the_ID();

 $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'post_status' => 'inherit',
    'post_parent' => $parent_id,
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);

$attachments = new WP_Query($args);
while ($attachments->have_posts()) {
       $attachments->the_post();
       //I pass $parent_id to get_permalink() because you was trying
       //to do that in your code but I'm not sure if this is what you want
       ?>
      <a class="postpreview" href="<?php echo get_permalink($parent_id); ?>"><?php echo wp_get_attachment_image(get_the_ID(), 'thumbnail') ?></a>

 <?php
 }
 wp_reset_postdata();
 ?>
```

Anyway, `new WP_query` is not much better than `get_posts()`, each one has its benefits and the better depends on what you want to do.

Comment: Hi there! Thanks for answering. Unfortunately, I tested it and replaced `$post->ID` with `$postid` (defined using `get_the_ID()`) but it still returns blank.

Comment: There was some syntax errors I copied from your code, see edited answer.

Comment: Gave it a shot but still nothing :( Really barking odd because even the HTML (like the link HTML) isn't displaying in source so it must not be working at all...

Comment: Try `var_dump($attachments)` after the query, and let's know what's it showing.

Comment: @MayeenulIslam Outputs a ton of blocks. Here's the first one: http://pastebin.com/uU5MyQ2m

Comment: @Anon Can you please provide a print screen with LightShot Desktop or something? In pastebin they are too messy - you know. :( But the good news is: your WP_Query is working and fetching data.

Comment: @MayeenulIslam haha I can agree with that. It's okay though -- I got it to work based on the dump! @cybnet 's code worked -- I just had to change his `post_status` to `'post_status' => 'inherit'` (attachments are all marked as inherit